# Slide Border onto screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make a border slide from the bottom of the screen into view, however i'm having issues getting the `ActualHeight` of my border control. Because this is animation code i'm putting it in the code-behind as it's the Views responsibility.

My Border has got it's `Loaded` event tied to this:

```
private void NotifcationWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SlideFromBottom(sender);
}
```

The `Sender` is the Border object, so the `SlideFromBottom` method SHOULD be able to use this object and get it's height as it has already been rendered.

```
public void SlideFromBottom(object sender)
{
    //The Notification container
    Border notification = (sender as Border);

    //The screen size
    var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),

        // Get the height and turn it to a negative value, and add screen height. 
        From = (notification.ActualHeight * -1),

        //Slide the border into view
        To = notification.ActualHeight
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, notification);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Margin.Bottom)"));

    sb.Begin();
}
```

I'm not receiving any errors, but the animation isn't playing, have I got something wrong? The Border is Vertically Aligned to the bottom, so the negative margin should take it off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing anything is that you haven't added the animation to the storyboard:

```
sb.Children.Add(animation);
```

Then there are some more problems. Such that a part of the margin cannot be animated separately. You would need a `ThicknessAnimation`.

But there is an easier solution. Use the `RenderTransform`. If you give your border the following render transform:

```
<Border>
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </Border.RenderTransform>
</Border>
```

, then you can animate it as follows:

```
// ...
var animation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),                

    From = notification.ActualHeight,

    To = 0
};
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, notification);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Y"));

sb.Children.Add(animation);
// ...
```

Comment: Crap how did I miss that! lol, also I can't really use RenderTransform to adjust the height, as the height will move with the content, I can't define an actual height, which is why i'm using Margin to move the entire thing.

Comment: I don't get it. You're using the `ActualHeight` in your example already. You're probably looking for the actual height of the window or parent.

Comment: Using ActualHeight to offset the Border using negative margin

Comment: I'm getting an error with `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(notification, new PropertyPath(Margin.Bottom));`, saying: `Object 'System.Double' cannot be used as an accessor paramater for a PropertyPath.` Any ideas?

Comment: As I said. You cannot animate `Margin.Bottom`. You can only animate `Margin` with a `ThicknessAnimation`. And since it is not an attached property, you should not use parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I used RenderTransform.Y on the container which gave me a similar effect as to what I wanted.